# Excel Pivot table filter

Tags: worksheet-function

I have created a pivot table in Microsoft Excel. In the count colum i would like to filter out all the zeros that was calculated using the sum function. But there isn't a filter option on that colum in the pivot table.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [ask] a good question? Have a look at e.g. [Filter data in a PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/filter-data-in-a-pivottable-cc1ed287-3a97-4e95-b377-ddfafe79fa8f)